# Laravel 5.1 - Javascript not loaded

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

My app gets the `views` from an `ajax` request by navigation.
So when i click a link in my menu i retrieve all the `Html` that my `view` contains.

My `javascript` is included inside the main `template` and of course all my calls works.
But once i need for example to create an `animated filter gallery` inside a specific view, the javascript for that view doesn't work.

This is how i've organized my app:

My template

```
<!-- !Doctype -->
@include('partials.doctype')

<!-- Menu -->
@include('partials.menu')

<!-- Cont -->
<section id="content-wrapper">
    @include('ajax.index')
</section>

<!-- Footer -->
@include('partials.footer')

<!-- Javascript -->
@include('partials.javascript')

</body>
</html>
```

My Controller (if there's an ajax call i retrieve the view without @extends() and @section(), otherwise i retrieve my full view):

```
// load page
public function loadPage($page){
    return (\Request::ajax()) ? view('ajax.'.$page)->render() : view('pages.'.$page);
}
```

My views:

For my purpose i've created 2 type of views, one extended and one with only the html i need from my ajax calls.

a) extended, it's inside "pages" folder:

```
@extends('main')
@section('cont')

@include('ajax.shop')

@stop
```

b) only html, for ajax calls, inside "ajax" folder:

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row page-title-box">
            <h3 class="page-number">N. 67</h3>
            <h1 class="page-title">Shop</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I don't understand where to put my `javascript` for this view if i need to implement an `animated filter gallery`. I've tried to put javascript inside the view but my app crashed.

Answer (score 0):

Your javascript should be in your public folder in a folder like public/js.

Then in your partials.javascript include your js:
`<script src="/js/main.js"></script>`

Comment: Inside partials.javascript there's all of my javascript. But is not loaded my specific function for the elements within the view i retrieve by ajax

Comment: Are your files named correctly? Your javascript file would be located in the resources/views/partials folder and be named javascript.blade.php